# Laravel + phpCAS: After login, redirect back to same page which required login

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I am developing a project using Laravel where we use phpCAS for user authentication. I am using this Laravel package for phpCAS:https://github.com/subfission/cas

After user gets authenticated, i wish to return him/her back to URL from which he/she was redirected to CAS server login.

I used url()->previous(); but it return wrong information in google chrome about referring URL (controller/action).

How can i achieve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use the `intended()` method

`The intended method on the redirector will redirect the user to the URL they were attempting to access before being intercepted by the authentication middleware. A fallback URI may be given to this method in case the intended destination is not available.`

example :  `return redirect()->intended('dashboard');`